# How to find the extreme point of an equation?

Tags: search

Input format:

1.n number of coefficient, number of search query m.

2. Following there will be n space separated coefficients.
3. Range specifying search area.

Sample input:
4 2
8 -543 540 60

-10 10
80 100

Sample output:

0.5
90

Expected complexity: log(Range)

What does the question wants me to do? I know the question sounds stupid.
I thought that I'm asked to find out the maxima of the equation's corresponding curve. But output given here doesn't match with manually found maxima. There's hint about local and global maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. Here I'm asked to find the extreme points, i.e. here I need to find the points with slope zero. Here we need to solve f'(x)=0 equation and for that we perform a binary search within the given range.